# How to get the specific variable value from nested JSON based on the specific variable

Tags: json, powershell, api, sonarqube

Below is the JSON Output got for one of the API call, now need to get the date based on the name value, for example want to iterate the JSON file and look for name variable value which is equal to 1.0 then want to have date which is `2018-12-13T18:04:42-0500`.

```
VERBOSE: {
    "paging":  {
                   "pageIndex":  1,
                   "pageSize":  100,
                   "total":  2
               },
    "analyses":  [
                     {
                         "key":  "xxxx",
                         "date":  "2019-06-07T18:04:56-0400",
                         "events":  [
                                        {
                                            "key":  "xxxxxx",
                                            "category":  "VERSION",
                                            "name":  "01.00"
                                        }
                                    ]
                     },
                     {
                         "key":  "yyyyyy",
                         "date":  "2018-12-13T18:04:42-0500",
                         "events":  [
                                        {
                                            "key":  "yyyyyy",
                                            "category":  "VERSION",
                                            "name":  "1.0"
                                        }
                                    ]
                     }
                 ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the entire JSON text in a string variable, say `$Json`, would this work for you?

```
$obj = $Json | ConvertFrom-Json
$obj.analyses | ForEach-Object { if ($_.Events.Name -eq "1.0"){$_.Date}}
```

Comment: @ATLANTAFALCONS Hint for a new contributor: If an answer solves your question or you find it helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote) (once you've got a [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) of 15 it will be seen)